# Very low resource usage on Openlitespeed (LOMP) on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, cache, litespeed

I have been testing a custom PHP script on LOMP (Ubuntu 22.04) running on VirtualBox (2GB/2Core). First, I tried Apache and upon benchmarking the script, it could complete 10K requests in ~36s - [ab benchmark on Apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTA4y.png)

Then, I installed LOMP and tried the same script after tweaking a few things under Server configuration (CPU Affinity, etc.). And, this time, it took 410s - [ab benchmark on OLS without LSMCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5tHU.png)

Later, I learned about LSMCD and gave it a try. This resulted in time being brought down to 185-250s - [ab benchmark on OLS without LSMCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEn3D.png)

What baffles me is the CPU usage when running OLS (with or without LSMCD). It never goes above 20% on a core, while the other core is under 5% when benchmarking. On the other hand, Apache easily hits 100% CPU when benchmarking. I believe I could get better results on OLS if I could make it use more CPU, but I don't have the least idea how. Have been searching for a solution for the past few days with no luck.

UPDATE - Just to check, reduced cores to 1, and re-ran ab. Guess what, the time remains the same, yet again proving that OLS refuses to use the machine's capacity to full. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I noticed this issue didn't exists with MySQL. Turns out mariaDB has a `max_connections` parameter. I edited it under the file `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` and then ran the benchmark. There's still some throttling after some time, that I need to figure out. But, CPU usage did hit close to 100%.